# Can't add additional items to React component (using Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I'm trying to define additional items into the current component I've got an error
**Property "" does not exist on type 'FC'**.

It pretty works in pure React but not with Typescript.
How I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

**Parent:**

```
    const Parent: FC = () => {
      return (
        <Children>
          <Children.El1 />
        </Children>
      );
    };
    
    export default Parent;
```

**Children:**

```
const El1: React.FC =() => {
    return (
       <div> element</div>
)}

interface Iprops {
children:any
}
    
const Children: React.FC<Iprops>= ({children}) => {
    return (
       {children}
)};

Children.El1 = El1 // here error
        
export default Children;
```

Comment: Aside: When using `const Children: React.FC =` you get a `children` prop *automatically* added to the available props: i.e. `const Children: React.FC = ({ children }) => {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `{}` from El1 props, because you are not specifiing object in prop types, and you have there empty object instead of undefined

And just my recommendation is to specify types of props like that:

```
interface Iprops {
children:any
}
    
const Children = ({children}: Iprops) => {
    return (
       {children}
)};
```

instead of specifying type of component. Its subjective but for me its easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for a tip and remark